# Pass Constant value in JPA query

Tags: spring

I want to pass constant values as below : Please help

I am using EntityManager to Pass constant values ("Successful") in JPA Query.

For Example:-

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a.alertId ,a.vmdId,"Successful") from Alertstatus a where a.alertId = ? and a.vmdId = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a parameter like that:

```
     Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a.alertId ,a.vmdId, :parameter) from 
     Alertstatus a where a.alertId = ? and a.vmdId = ?")
     .setParameter("parameter", "Successful");
```